# Access to path denied when i write and save the file on server

Tags: asp.net

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\HealthCard\NewsTextFiles\News.html' is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
```

I am using ckeditor . Edit the file on server and save the file on server. It is not working on server but it is well working on my localmachine.

Here is code of edit and save button.

```
protected void btnSaveNews_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string str = Ckeditor.Text;

        string str1 = Server.HtmlDecode(str);

        //lblText.Text = str2;


        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/NewsTextFiles/News.html"), FileMode.Create , FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(fs);
        wr.Write(str1);


        wr.Dispose();
        fs.Dispose();

        pnleditor.Visible = false;
        upleditor.Update();
        upleditor.Visible = false;

    }
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception, at `wr.Write(str1)` ?

Comment: i get the exception on the server  it is working fine in my local machine.in error log it is showing meesage....System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\HealthCard\NewsTextFiles\News.html' is denied.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the user your Application Pool is running as has write permissions on that file / folder.

This might be:

`IIS_USR` or `Network Service` (can also be others).